# Nginx/Webdav/Put - Content-Range support

Tags: nginx, http-headers, webdav

I have installed [WebDav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) extensions (--with-http_dav_module,nginx-dav-ext-module) for Nginx, and now I can write, read files using this protocol.

But I need to write data part by part with `PUT` method, I've found that I can use `Content-Range` header for this, but I can't find any extension for Nginx to work with `Content-Range`.

How can I achieve this? Any suggestions?

I can't read data from server and append new data to current and then write it (data is too big).

Answer (score 2):

Using `Content-Range` for PUT is explicitly forbidden by the HTTP standard, and a really bad idea.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4

I wrote a simple specification that allows you to append data:

http://sabre.io/dav/http-patch/

But it does mean that you need to run sabre/dav, and not nginx's webdav module.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i can't use sabre/dav, because in the project I'm working on has been written a lot of code by other developers (my colleagues) using nginx and webdav, probably i will try to achieve my goal other way

Comment: If you are just talking to nginx using the WebDAV protocol, you should be able to use it as a drop-in replacement. This is only not true if you wrote custom nginx code, presumably in C++.